# How to Vim multiply symbol "a" with a number from clipboard?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I need to multiply symbol "a" with a number from clipboard.
For example
`3a = aaa`

In clipboard register is `@+`.
May be to do that throw command line mode, but don't understand how.

Comment: Where does the symbol a reside? In a register? Or is it really literal `a`? Or a selection of edited text? Anyway have you tried `:help repeat()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
It's working. 
Copy number in @+
```
<c-r> in insert mode
:repeat('a', @+)
```

Comment: @Serii feel free to post your answer such that other can vote for it. You could also accept your own answer after a delay of two days. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the number is in the `+` register, you can insert the result of a `repeat()` expression by doing (from insert mode):

```
<c-r>=repeat('a', @+)<enter>
```